# SQLAlchemy and PyTest: how change database during tests?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a "batch" process in Python (without use of any framework).
Project configuration is in a `config.ini` file

```sh
[db]
db_uri = mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306/manage
```

I have another file `config.test` to swap during test

```sh
[db]
db_uri = sqlite://
```

I have a simple `test_sample.py`

```py
# tests/test_sample.py

import pytest
import shutil
import os

import batch
import batch_manage.utils.getconfig as getconfig_class

class TestClass():
    def setup_method(self, method):
        """ Rename the config """
        shutil.copyfile("config.ini", "config.bak")
        os.remove('config.ini')
        shutil.copyfile("config.test", "config.ini")

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        """ Replace the config """
        shutil.copyfile("config.bak", "config.ini")
        os.remove('config.bak')


    def test_can_get_all_data_from_table(self):
        conf = getconfig_class.get_config('db')
        db_uri = conf.get('db_uri')
        assert db_uri == "sqlite://"
        # This pass! ok!
        people = batch.get_all_people()
        assert len(people) == 0
        # This fails, because counts the records in production database
```

`db_uri` assert is ok (at test time is sqlite and not the mysql) but len is not 0, but 42 (the number of records inside MySql database.

I suspect an issue with the session of SqlAlchemy ORM. I made several try without possibility to overwrite / delete it.

The rest of code is really simple:

```py
# batch_manage/models/base.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import batch_manage.utils.getconfig as getconfig_class

conf = getconfig_class.get_config('db')
db_uri = conf.get('db_uri')

engine = create_engine(db_uri)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

```py
# batch_manage/models/persone.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date

from batch_manage.models.base import Base


class Persone(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persone"

    idpersona = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = Column(String)
    created_at = Column(Date)

    def __init__(self, nome, created_at):
        self.nome = nome
        self.created_at = created_at
```

And the `batch.py` itself

```py
# batch.py
import click

from batch_manage.models.base import Session
from batch_manage.models.persone import Persone

def get_all_people():
    """ Get all people from database """
    session = Session()

    people = session.query(Persone).all()

    return people


@click.command()
def batch():
    click.echo("------------------------------")
    click.echo("Running Batch")
    click.echo("------------------------------")

    people = get_all_people()

    for item in people:
        print(f"Persona con ID {item.idpersona} creata il {item.created_at}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    batch()
```

### First "solution" (not elegant, I would refactor this)

I managed for the moment changing test with:

```py
def test_can_get_all_data_from_table(self):
        conf = getconfig_class.get_config('db')
        db_uri = conf.get('db_uri')
        assert db_uri == "sqlite://"

        from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine(db_uri)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()

        people = batch.get_all_people(session)
        assert len(people) == 0
```

And `get_all_people` method with

```py
def get_all_people(session = None):
    """ Get all people from database """
    if session is None:
      session = Session()

    people = session.query(Persone).all()

    return people
```

But this solution is not elegant and decrease also code coverage, for a if path not followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I follow your code correctly , it looks like you're importing your ORM stuff *before your tests are setup*. Here's your current order of operations:

1. `batch.py` is imported.
2. Your other modules are imported.
3. In the top-level module code of your `models/base.py` file, you configure a database to use.
4. Your test class sets up, changing the configuration *after it's already been loaded.*

So, to the solutions:

### Import all your modules inside your test itself

If you simply want to change the order of operations, don't import your code until you're inside your test. That's often good test practice anyway:

```py
class TestClass():
    ... (your existing code) ...

    def test_can_get_all_data_from_table(self):
        # ONLY import stuff inside your test
        from batch_manage.models.base import Session
        from batch_manage.models.persone import Persone
```

That will likely solve your immediate problem, but there is probably a more elegant solution

### Do not immediately configure your database

I don't know if you're using Flask, but either way, [the Flask testing documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/) has some good instructions on how to setup a test database. You'll want to configure your database URL after your modules are imported.

For example:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

(your models)
```

Notice that I haven't defined an engine yet. I can do that *at runtime*.

```
def setup_engine():
    engine = create_engine(db_url)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
```

Inside your main code, before you serve content to users, you'd call `setup_engine`. In your test environment, you'd call your own `setup_engine` that binds instead to a test environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it ASAP. You are right about order of import and... no, I don't use for this project no framework at all. Thank you for your time spent!

Comment: At the end, I use your first solution (import only when necessary).. and.. it works :) Thank you very much.